# Required fields in an association model is not displaying as required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two classes, for example:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

When I post the form, only in the "Person.Name" attribute appears the message "The Name field is required."

Why it doens´t appears in the "HomeAddress.StreetName" attribute?

```
@model SqlExpress.Models.Person

<form asp-action="Create">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <input asp-for="HomeAddress.StreetName" />
    ...
```

Comment: when you *post the form*? do you mean when you hit the create button, the only validation that appears is for the `Name` property, if you leave both the `Name` and `StreetName` properties blank?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, Yes, that´s correct.

Comment: can you post your *Create* view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works pretty well with Razor view engine.
Did you forgot to add the validation message field similar to the one mentioned below?

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeAddress.StreetName)
```

Comment: You are correct. I was using only data-valmsg-for="StreetName" and the correct is data-valmsg-for="HomeAddress.StreetName"